# Perform stemming on csv file using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am new to python and Pandas and want to perform stemming on a CSV file column named 'Body' using Pandas. My code is as below:

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer

answers= pd.read_csv('F:/mtech/Project/answer_sample.csv')
porter_stemmer = PorterStemmer()
#print(answers.head())
#print(answers.loc[0:,"Body"])
df= pd.read_csv('F:/mtech/Project/answer_sample.csv','utf-8')
df['Body'] = df['Body'].str.lower().str.split()
stop = stopwords.words('english')
df['Body']= df['Body'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in stop])

df['Body_Tokenized']= df['Body'].apply(lambda x : filter(None,x.split(' ')))

df['Body_Stemmed']= df['Body_Tokenized'].apply(lambda x : [porter_stemmer.stem(y) for y in x])

df.to_csv('F:/mtech/Project/answer_swr_stem.csv')
print("Done..")
```

I am able to perform stopword removal but while stemming, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\mtech\DATASET\answer_pd.py", line 10, in <module>
    df= pd.read_csv('F:/mtech/Project/answer_sample.csv','utf-8')
  File "C:\Users\Ayushi Misra\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 646, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Ayushi Misra\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 401, in _read
    data = parser.read()
  File "C:\Users\Ayushi Misra\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 939, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\Ayushi Misra\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1997, in read
    alldata = self._rows_to_cols(content)
  File "C:\Users\Ayushi Misra\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2551, in _rows_to_cols
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Expected 1 fields in line 2853, saw 2. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.
```

Need help!

Comment: You never use the `answers` variable created in the line `answers= pd.read_csv('F:/mtech/Project/answer_sample.csv')`. Try deleting that, and replacing `df= pd.read_csv('F:/mtech/Project/answer_sample.csv','utf-8')` with `df= pd.read_csv('F:/mtech/Project/answer_sample.csv')`.

Comment: Did you look at the data for the possible Error mentioned in the Traceback? Please post the line in the csv that was mentioned in the Traceback and and a few lines around it.